# Ejecutar un método en un jButton en Java

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans

Hola quiero llamar a un método para ejecutarla en otra clase dentro un botón pero este metodo tiene los siguientes parámetros c, mod lo eh intentado así.

Este es el metodo

```
public void mostarCasillas(Casillas c,Usuario mod){}
```

Lo llamo dentro del botón pero así pero no me ejecuta nada.

```
private void btnMostrarCasillaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    Casillas c = new Casillas();
    Usuario m = new Usuario();
    mostarCasillas(c, m);
}
```

-creo que es por lo que hago una nueva instancias y entonces los datos que traen se pierden
Habrá otra manera? gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué hace tu método `mostarCasillas()`? Por otro lado, le estás pasando instancias vacías.

Comment: el método muestra casillas en el panel lo que quiero es ejecutar ese método des de un boton (el método esta bien porque cuando lo llamo del constructor si me muestra todo bien ya que tiene los mismos parámetros const(Casillas c, Usuario mod)  y llamo al metodo mostrarCasillas(c, mod) y todo bien) pero al momento del llamarlo desde un boton no me deja